# pasar ID desde front a backend Laravel y livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Como paso un valor desde un boton a una consulta de un metodo en backend?

tengo este metodo en mi backend:

```
public function printIndividualPDF(HistoryOrderState $historyOrderState)
{
   $internalOrderStatus = Order::where('prestashop_order_id', $historyOrderState->prestasop_order_id)
   //dd($internalOrderStatus);
   ->update([
   'id_state_id' => 2,
   ]);
}
```

y tengo este codigo en mi boton en el front con livewire:

```
<div class="flex justify-end">
  <button class="btn" 
  wire.model="printPDF()" 
  wire:click="('printIndividualPDF', {{$historyOrderState->prestashop_order_id}} )"
  > Imprimir PDF </button>
  {{ $historyOrderState->prestashop_order_id }}
</div>
```

Este codigo del boton lo tengo dentro de un foreach donde tengo el $historyOrderState y aqui veo que estoy obteniendo el id o valor correcto, lo que no se es como pasarlo al metodo para que haga la consulta al backend... Hago mención a que estos botones son partes de la vida index, estos los ejecuto todos desde donde listo mis registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes pasar los parámetros tal como si utilizaras la función adentro del controlador, es decir:

```
wire:click="printIndividualPDF({{ $historyOrderState->prestashop_order_id }})"
```

Pero tu función recibe una instancia de `HistoryOrderState` cuando lo declaras así `HistoryOrderState $historyOrderState`.

Si únicamente necesitas el `id` yo no enviaría todo el `HistoryOrderState`, de esta forma:

```
public function printIndividualPDF($orderId)
{
   //dd($orderId);   // Por si quieres ver lo que está recibiendo
   Order::where('prestashop_order_id', $orderId)->update(['id_state_id' => 2]);
}
```